# R - Need help reading a collection of dates from a text file (likely a conversion issue) and displaying them on a time graph

Tags: r

I've been trying to fix this issue for a full day and I know that it's something simple, but I've just run out of things to try and I don't know what to do now.

Here is the error that I got when I tried to run the code:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So here is what I'm trying to do:

1) Read a list of values and a list of dates(with day, month, and year) each from their own txt file.

2) Convert the extracted list of dates into the date format to be used.

3) Create a time graph using the two lists

4) Create a slope on the graph with the original plot data to indicate a mean/forecast line.

Here is the code:

The following lines were simply used to create the sample data:

```
Quantity <- c(5,3,8,4,0,5,2,7,4,2,6,8,4,7,8,9,4,6)
Time <- c("2010-01-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-08-03", "2011-02-04", "2011-11-05", "2011-12-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-08-30", "2013-04-16", "2013-03-18", "2014-02-22", "2014-01-27", "2015-12-15", "2015-09-28", "2016-05-04", "2017-11-07", "2017-09-22", "2017-04-04")
```

The sample data was then stored to their respective files:

```
write.table(Quantity,file="C:/Users/Ryan/Desktop/Function/Quantity.txt",quote=F)
write.table(Time,file="C:/Users/Ryan/Desktop/Function/Time.txt",quote=F)
```

Then I attempted to plot the data onto a graph (This line was where I attempted to convert the Time vector to dates before plotting):

```
plot(x=strptime(Time, "%Y-%m-%d"),y=Quantity,xlab="Time",ylab="Quantity",main="Stock Quantity vs Time")
```

Here is the code to calculate and display the slope:

```
Line <- lm(Quantity ~ Time)
Slope <- coef(Line)[2]

if(Slope >= 0) 
{
  #abline(Line,col="green")
  legend("topright",c("Stock levels","Quantity mean and forecast"),lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("black","green"))
} else {
  #abline(Line,col="red")
  legend("topright",c("Stock levels","Quantity mean and forecast"),lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("black","red"))
}
```

When I use the code, but simply use a vector of numbers from 1 to 18 instead of the 18 dates, everything works fine (the plot displays, and the mean line displays). I just can't get it to work with dates.

Comment: What if you change `Line <- lm(Quantity ~ as.Date(Time, "%Y-%m-%d")` in your code?. If not you need to put an example of a list as data to play with.

Comment: Could you please post an example of your list?

Comment: x
1 2010-01-01
2 2010-07-02
3 2010-08-03
4 2011-02-04
5 2011-11-05
6 2011-12-06
7 2012-06-07
8 2012-08-30
9 2013-04-16
10 2013-03-18
11 2014-02-22
12 2014-01-27
13 2015-12-15
14 2015-09-28
15 2016-05-04
16 2017-11-07
17 2017-09-22
18 2017-04-04

Comment: They are all on separate lines including the x

Comment: The format for the time can be anything, just so long as it reads right.

Comment: I think that if your `unlist` your list should work. Something like :`plot(x=as.Date(unlist(Time)),y=Quantity,xlab="Time",ylab="Quantity",main="Stock Quantity vs Time")`. Also Dont forget to do the same in `Line <- lm(Quantity ~as.Date(unlist(Time)))`. Finally, if your Quantity is also a list just `unlist` it

Comment: Sweet. Thank you very much, that fixed it ;). I have one last question, the lines on the graph are sometimes moving backwards (meaning that the lists of dates hasn't been ordered by time). How can I remedy this?

Comment: I dont understant what "moving backwards" means. It is a line... You can use `order` to sort your dates (Not sure if that is what you need)

Comment: I have updated the answer with `unlist`

Comment: Oh sorry. I wasn't being clear. I made the graph to show as a line graph, and since the dates of the list aren't in order, some of the lines are going backwards (or leftward) on the graph in 'time', which shouldn't happen. How can i re-order the list of times so that they flow in chronological order?

Comment: Like this `Time_ordered<-Time[order(as.Date(unlist(Time)))]`

Comment: I plugged it in, but its not working. It's now giving the original error of: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Sorry, this is just another question, please accept the answer if you want and post this problem as different question

Comment: I understand. Thank you for all of your help. I made a good deal of progress :). I don't think I'll need to make another post, I should be able to figure out the stragglers on my own ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` and read `as.Date`

```
Quantity <- list(5,3,8,4,0,5,2,7,4,2,6,8,4,7,8,9,4,6)
Time <- list("2010-01-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-08-03", "2011-02-04", "2011-11-05", "2011-12-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-08-30", "2013-04-16", "2013-03-18", "2014-02-22", "2014-01-27", "2015-12-15", "2015-09-28", "2016-05-04", "2017-11-07", "2017-09-22", "2017-04-04")
plot(x=as.Date(unlist(Time)),y=unlist(Quantity),xlab="Time",ylab="Quantity",main="Stock Quantity vs Time")


Line <- lm(unlist(Quantity) ~as.Date(unlist(Time)))

Slope <- coef(Line)[2]

if(Slope >= 0) 
{
  abline(Line,col="green")
  legend("topright",c("Stock levels","Quantity mean and forecast"),lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("black","green"))
} else {
  abline(Line,col="red")
  legend("topright",c("Stock levels","Quantity mean and forecast"),lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("black","red"))
}
```

For your example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but my main problem was that I can't convert the extracted data from the time list to dates. when I create the graph, it tries to plot it treating the dates as 'doubles' and sometimes plots an immensely small fraction. In your example, your showing the conversion to dates from the sample data, but i first need to extract and then convert.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I tried, but it gave the same error. I have also already been trying to move the conversion from one place to another, but I think what it is doing is extracting the data as a strange fraction(e.g.1/1/2010), and trying to convert that to a date, which can't work. I think its having trouble reading from the file itself.